# While using custom callback in Earlystopping callback not works

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a project where I am using custom callback with earlystopping callback, in this my model training not stops even `val_loss` not improving much.

Here is my implmentation:

```py
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred = self.model.predict(self.x)
        error_rate =  np.sum(self.y == y_pred)
        print(f'Error number:: {error_rate}')
        logs['error_rate'] = error_rate


early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=2)
custom_callback = CustomCallback(X_data, y_data)


model.fit(train_data, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(cv_data, y_cv), callbacks=[early_stop, custom_callback])
```

What is wrong in my implementation?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: training does not stops, even my validation loss is not improving much

Comment: In your `earlystop` callback, `patience=2`. Do you mean that training does not stop even after 2 epochs with no decreased `val_loss`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a custom metric instead of a callback?

```
def error_rate(y_true, y_pred):
    rate = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, y_pred), K.floatx())
    return keras.backend.sum(rate)
```

Are you passing label numbers or one hot tensors as y?? Usually it should be rounding first (there will be nothing equal if you don't)

```
def error_rate(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.cast(K.greater(y_pred, 0.5), K.floatx())
    ate = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, y_pred), K.floatx())
    return keras.backend.sum(rate)
```

Use it as a metric:

```
model.compile(......, metrics=[error_rate, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the **min_delta** argument in **EarlyStopping** with some value so that an absolute change less than min_delta will count as no improvement and it will stop training.